# Filtering results from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I need a dropdown to filter some results from a table. So far I turned the table into an object and got the selected value in the dropdown but I can't filter the results because the filter function only works with arrays. It's supposed show all that the class `subtema` equals the value of the dropdown. How can I make this filter work?

```js
var arrayValores = [];
var objecto;

function converter() {
  $("#tabela tr").each(function() {
    var arrayRow = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td');
    if (tableData.length > 0) {
      tableData.each(function() {
        arrayRow.push($(this).text());
      });
      arrayValores.push(arrayRow);
    }
  });

  objecto = arrayValores.map(function(x) {
    return {
      "tema": x[0],
      "subtema": x[1],
      "cenario": x[2],
      "motivo": x[3],
      "tipo": x[4],
      "subtipo": x[5],
      "observacao": x[6]
    }
  });
}

function filtrarAnt(valor) {
  console.log(valor);
  var resultado = objecto.filter(objecto.subtema === valor);
  if (resultado === true) {
    console.log("it's working!");
  } else {
    console.log("not working");
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="converter()">
  <table id="tabela" class="hide">
    <tr class="row1">
      <td>Atendimento</td>
      <td>Transferências</td>
      <td>Para a Retenção</td>
      <td>Transferencia</td>
      <td>Retencion</td>
      <td>Retencion</td>
      <td>Deves especificar o assunto tratado em chamada e o que motivou a transferência.</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row2">
      <td>Atendimento</td>
      <td>Transferências</td>
      <td>Para o departamento MEDEM</td>
      <td>Transferencia</td>
      <td>Empresas</td>
      <td>Empresas</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row3">
      <td>Atendimento</td>
      <td>Transferências</td>
      <td>Para as Reclamações (GEIR)</td>
      <td>Transferencia</td>
      <td>Reclamaciones</td>
      <td>Reclamaciones</td>
      <td>Deves especificar o assunto tratado em chamada e o que motivou a transferência.</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row4">
      <td>Atendimento</td>
      <td>Transferências</td>
      <td>Para a linha de assistência técnica do SUE, em caso de urgência elétrica reportada pelo cliente</td>
      <td>Transferencia</td>
      <td>SAT Productos y servicios</td>
      <td>SAT Productos y servicios</td>
      <td>Obrigatoriamente Deves incluir na interação uma breve descrição da chamada e o número do pedido que registaste em IC (nº de processo).</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row5">
      <td>Atendimento</td>
      <td>Transferências</td>
      <td>Para Smart Services, no âmbito de Smart Mobility</td>
      <td>Información comercial</td>
      <td>Servicios</td>
      <td>Smart Mobility</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row6">
      <td>Atendimento</td>
      <td>Transferências</td>
      <td>Para Smart Services, no âmbito de Smart Solar</td>
      <td>Información comercial</td>
      <td>Servicios</td>
      <td>Smart Solar</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row7">
      <td>Atendimento</td>
      <td>Atualização BD</td>
      <td>Houve a atualização da Base de Dados do cliente</td>
      <td>Mantenimiento</td>
      <td>Cliente</td>
      <td>Unificación DNI</td>
      <td>Deves indicar na interação quais os dados que alteraste/atualizaste.</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row8">
      <td>Atendimento</td>
      <td>Avarias</td>
      <td>Dei o número para avarias de Eletricidade (E-Redes)</td>
      <td>Averías</td>
      <td>Electricidad</td>
      <td>Outra distribuidora</td>
      <td>Deves descrever, de forma objetiva, o assunto que foi tratado em chamada.</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row9">
      <td>Atendimento</td>
      <td>Avarias</td>
      <td>Dei o número para avarias de gás (Distribuidores da lista, no Diogo)</td>
      <td>Averías</td>
      <td>Gas</td>
      <td>Distribuidora</td>
      <td>Deves descrever, de forma objetiva, o assunto que foi tratado em chamada.</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row10">
      <td>Atendimento</td>
      <td>Chamada caiu</td>
      <td>A chamada do cliente caiu</td>
      <td>Cierre rápido</td>
      <td>Llamada interrumpida</td>
      <td>Llamada interrumpida</td>
      <td>Deves indicar o contexto/tema da chamada, caso tenha havido tempo para o cliente explicar.</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row11">
      <td>Atendimento</td>
      <td>LOPD</td>
      <td>O cliente não fornece dados suficientes para validação do LOPD</td>
      <td>Cierre rápido</td>
      <td>No pasa LOPD</td>
      <td>No pasa LOPD</td>
      <td>Deves indicar quais os dados que o cliente indicou</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <select onchange="filtrarAnt(this.value)">
    <option>subtema</option>
    <option>Transferências</option>
    <option>atualização bd</option>
    <option>avarias</option>
    <option>chamada caiu</option>
    <option>lopd</option>
  </select>

  <script data-require="jquery@2.0.3" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure i follow the logic, `objecto` is an array of your table, and then I don't think you will get the correct result with `objecto.filter(objecto.subtema === valor)`. But you can try this https://jsfiddle.net/ukgndwm0/

Comment: Are columns (useful) or rows (not so useful) being filtered?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that the use of `filter()` is incorrect. You need to work with the object passed as an argument to than handler, not the `objecto` variable from the outer scope. From there you need to check the `length` of the resulting array to see if any matches were found:

```
function filtrarAnt(valor) {
  var resultado = objecto.filter(o => o.subtema === valor);
  if (resultado.length > 0) {
    console.log("it's working!");
  } else {
    console.log("not working");
  }
}
```

However, your code can be massively simplified. You don't *have* to use an array to determine if a match was found from the table, you can check the DOM directly. This saves the need to build the array in the first place and turns the logic of the code, effectively, in to a single line:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('select').on('change', e => {
    $("#tabela tr").hide().filter(`:has(td:nth-child(2):contains("${e.target.value}"))`).show();
  })
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option>subtema</option>
  <option>Transferências</option>
  <option>atualização bd</option>
  <option>avarias</option>
  <option>chamada caiu</option>
  <option>lopd</option>
</select>

<table id="tabela" class="hide">
  <tr class="row1">
    <td>Atendimento</td>
    <td>Transferências</td>
    <td>Para a Retenção</td>
    <td>Transferencia</td>
    <td>Retencion</td>
    <td>Retencion</td>
    <td>Deves especificar o assunto tratado em chamada e o que motivou a transferência.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row2">
    <td>Atendimento</td>
    <td>Transferências</td>
    <td>Para o departamento MEDEM</td>
    <td>Transferencia</td>
    <td>Empresas</td>
    <td>Empresas</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row3">
    <td>Atendimento</td>
    <td>Transferências</td>
    <td>Para as Reclamações (GEIR)</td>
    <td>Transferencia</td>
    <td>Reclamaciones</td>
    <td>Reclamaciones</td>
    <td>Deves especificar o assunto tratado em chamada e o que motivou a transferência.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row4">
    <td>Atendimento</td>
    <td>Transferências</td>
    <td>Para a linha de assistência técnica do SUE, em caso de urgência elétrica reportada pelo cliente</td>
    <td>Transferencia</td>
    <td>SAT Productos y servicios</td>
    <td>SAT Productos y servicios</td>
    <td>Obrigatoriamente Deves incluir na interação uma breve descrição da chamada e o número do pedido que registaste em IC (nº de processo).</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row5">
    <td>Atendimento</td>
    <td>Transferências</td>
    <td>Para Smart Services, no âmbito de Smart Mobility</td>
    <td>Información comercial</td>
    <td>Servicios</td>
    <td>Smart Mobility</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row6">
    <td>Atendimento</td>
    <td>Transferências</td>
    <td>Para Smart Services, no âmbito de Smart Solar</td>
    <td>Información comercial</td>
    <td>Servicios</td>
    <td>Smart Solar</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row7">
    <td>Atendimento</td>
    <td>Atualização BD</td>
    <td>Houve a atualização da Base de Dados do cliente</td>
    <td>Mantenimiento</td>
    <td>Cliente</td>
    <td>Unificación DNI</td>
    <td>Deves indicar na interação quais os dados que alteraste/atualizaste.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row8">
    <td>Atendimento</td>
    <td>Avarias</td>
    <td>Dei o número para avarias de Eletricidade (E-Redes)</td>
    <td>Averías</td>
    <td>Electricidad</td>
    <td>Outra distribuidora</td>
    <td>Deves descrever, de forma objetiva, o assunto que foi tratado em chamada.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row9">
    <td>Atendimento</td>
    <td>Avarias</td>
    <td>Dei o número para avarias de gás (Distribuidores da lista, no Diogo)</td>
    <td>Averías</td>
    <td>Gas</td>
    <td>Distribuidora</td>
    <td>Deves descrever, de forma objetiva, o assunto que foi tratado em chamada.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row10">
    <td>Atendimento</td>
    <td>Chamada caiu</td>
    <td>A chamada do cliente caiu</td>
    <td>Cierre rápido</td>
    <td>Llamada interrumpida</td>
    <td>Llamada interrumpida</td>
    <td>Deves indicar o contexto/tema da chamada, caso tenha havido tempo para o cliente explicar.</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row11">
    <td>Atendimento</td>
    <td>LOPD</td>
    <td>O cliente não fornece dados suficientes para validação do LOPD</td>
    <td>Cierre rápido</td>
    <td>No pasa LOPD</td>
    <td>No pasa LOPD</td>
    <td>Deves indicar quais os dados que o cliente indicou</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script data-require="jquery@2.0.3" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. However I realized I didn't explain myself correctly since English isn't my mother language and I'm really sorry for that. The table it's hidden with `display: none;` and then maybe use `.write()` to create a second dropdown to filter `nth-child(3)` to finally write in 4 different divs the remain 4 td.